# Can I chain API calls through drush?

Tags: api, documentation, drush, chaining

API chaining works well in Javascript and PHP. For example, I can retrieve a contact's email addresses using this code generated by the API Explorer:

Php

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'getsingle', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'return' => "display_name",
  'id' => 41194,
  'api.Email.get' => array('return' => "email"),
));
```

Javascript

```
CRM.api3('Contact', 'getsingle', {
  "sequential": 1,
  "return": "display_name",
  "id": 41194,
  "api.Email.get": {"return":"email"}
}).done(function(result) {
  // do something
});
```

However, the drush command generated by the API explorer doesn't work:

```
drush cvapi Contact.getsingle sequential=1 return="display_name" id=41194 api.Email.get={"return":"email"}
# Gives me the contact just fine, but no email
```

Is there any way to coax drush cvapi into processing chained api calls? If it's not currently possible, is anybody working on it?

In the meantime, how can I help to correct the API Explorer so it doesn't produce non-working drush commands?

Comment: Just to note that for the example you give, you can use ' return="display_name,email" ' without chaining, though that doesn't help the general case.

Comment: Thanks @Aidan -- that will give me the primary email, but with chaining in JS or PHP I can retrieve multiple emails associated with a contact.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Drush can read parameters from standard input in JSON format if you supply the argument `--in=json`. This is what we need for API chaining, because chaining uses nested parameters, and in contrast to a flat list of command line arguments (the default way to pass parameters to `drush cvapi`, JSON can handle nesting. So to retrieve the email addresses for contact ID 41194 along with that contact's display name, use:

```
echo '{
  "sequential": 1,
  "return": "display_name",
  "id": 41194,
  "api.Email.get": {"return":"email"}
}' | drush cvapi Contact.getsingle --in=json
```

Comment: This is good, with a couple caveats: the output is hard to parse, and it doesn't work on Joomla/WordPress. To resolve those issues, change `drush cvapi` to [`cv api`]( https://github.com/civicrm/cv). That notation works on more CMS's and supports better output formats (JSON, PHP serialize(), and sometimes CSV).