# Updating an option value with drush cvapi

Tags: api, cli

I'm suprised that it is so hard to update an option value in a certain group using our API.

I have been writing scripts as follows:

1. get option group id where option group name = X (save as OptionGroupIDX)
2. get option value id where option value name = Y and option group id = OptionGroupIDX =(save as OptionValueIDY)
3. update OptionValueIDY title to Z

I'd like to be able to write scripts that look more like:

1. update the option value X in option group Y to value Z

The real world shell script I'm using at the minute is as follows:

```
OPTION_GROUP_ID=`drush cvapi OptionGroup.getvalue return=id name=from_email_address`
OPTION_VALUE_ID=`drush cvapi OptionValue.getvalue return=id option_group_id=$OPTION_GROUP_ID`
drush cvapi OptionValue.create id=$OPTION_VALUE_ID label='"Fixed" <info@fixed.org>'
```

Anyone able to help me get it closer to a one liner? Would be awesome if so because patterns like this seem to come up a fair amount when I'm working with the API. Would chaining help here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Civi 4.6+, you can use pseudoconstants instead of IDs in many places - including for `option_group_id`.  Civi 4.7 expands the number of places you can use it.

So you can get this down to 2 lines by replacing the first two with:

```
OPTION_VALUE_ID=`drush cvapi OptionValue.getvalue return=id option_group_id=from_email_address`.
```

Here's the trick: If the API Explorer allows you to select the value from a select list, that means that pseudoconstant substitution is available on that field.

Unfortunately, I don't think you're going to get this down to one API call.  `create` requires an ID; you're just not going to get the ID without a `get` call.

EDIT: It MAY be possible to get this down to one line!  See "options.match" and "options.match-mandatory" on [this page](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Using+the+API).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a case for API chaining. This or something like it *should* work:

```
drush cvapi OptionValue.getvalue return=id option_group_id=from_email_address \
    api.OptionValue.create={label:'"Fixed" <info@fixed.org>'}
```

Unfortunately, API chaining via drush [does not appear to work](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/10887/446). Thanks to @noah-miller for pointing that out. I tried chaining via cli.php and that doesn't appear to work either. It seems not to register the *api.Entity.action* parameter at all (which makes me optimistic it is not a difficult fix).

Jon's suggestion could be combined with what you already have to put it on one line, though the readability of this code is questionable:

```
drush cvapi OptionValue.create id=`drush cvapi OptionValue.getvalue \
    return=id option_group_id=from_email_address` label='"Fixed" <info@fixed.org>'
```